# How can I avoid using .net Core DI container?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

It seems like microsoft is making it super hard if not impossible to avoid using their .net core DI container.

I am migrating several solutions and don't want to replace the custom DI container that I use across my solutions.

Currently I can run without registering any service but as soon as I declare an interface in any controller's constructor, core tries to resolve using their DI container which is very very annoying.

Anybody has any success overriding this behavior,

Comment: The .NET Core DI infrastructure allows you to replace the default container with anything else you like (such as Autofac, https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) So read the documentation of the DI framework you chose and see what exactly you should do to integrate.

Comment: From your question it is unclear what it is you want to achieve. Do you want to prevent using the Dependency Injection pattern completely, do you want to apply DI but prevent using *any* DI Container (a.k.a. [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)), you want to use another DI Container, just not MS.DI? You need to answer these questions before we can answer your question.

Comment: I have custom DI container that I want to use instead of .net core one.